# OpenGL + Mesa 3D + MinGW

Tags: opengl, mingw

I program C++ applications on (Ubuntu) Linux and compile them to 2 operating systems: natively to *Linux* by using "g++" (GNU C++ compiler) and cross-compile them to *Windows* by using "i386-mingw32-g++" (MinGW C++ cross-compiler).

Now, I am trying to cross-compile "OpenGL" applications (from Linux to Windows) - for that I need some OpenGL library files.
As an implementation of OpenGL, I use "Mesa 3D" open source library. Fortunately, Ubuntu offers "precompiled" mesa3d libraries (*libgl1-mesa-dev* and *libglu1-mesa-dev*) for Linux, but unfortunately, there are not any precompiled libraries for using with MinGW cross-compiler (thus Windows versions of them) - so I "MUST" manually compile them "from source" (which can be downloaded from http://www.mesa3d.org homepage).

But I have no idea to do that. Within the mesa3d source code, there are some documents how to build the libraries for some specific platforms - specifically there is "README.MINGW32" readme file.
But just on the first lines there is some command

```
mingw32-make -f Makefile.mgw [OPTIONS...]
```

which I cannot run because I don't have any "mingw32-make" program installed. By other softwares, I used to build them with the "classic"

```
./configure -> make -> make install
```

procedure, but this is not working on mesa3d libraries.
For example, I have also tried

```
./configure --host=i386-mingw32
```

and it has been configured ok but after typing

```
make
```

it threw some error

```
error: #error No PIPE_SUBSYSTEM_WINDOWS_xxx subsystem defined.
```

and now I am LOST :-( .

So does anybody know how to build the mesa3d libraries for using them with mingw32?

*P.S.:* And of course, **I DON'T WANT** to use Microsoft Visual Studio NEVER MORE :-) . And also I would like to do all the required things to build up OpenGL environment from Linux and using mingw32 for cross-compiling. I hope it is possible.

*P.S.2:* On http://www.mesa3d.org/systems.html page there is written that using MinGW with Mesa 3D is "deprecated". I am on the right way to use it just that way?

Comment: Just wondering... OpenGL is usually used to access hardware accelerated 3D. By using mesa on windows, you resort to a software implementation on windows. Is that really what you want ? Otherwise, you just need to use the windows-provided opengl libraries.

Comment: My primary goal is being "architecture independent" when writing c++ code -> therefore I thought that using a cross-platform library ("mesa3d" in this case) is a good way to achieve that, I don't know, maybe I am wrong.

So should I understand it so that in "each Windows" there are some "libraries" that implements OpenGL and when I write some OpenGL code on my Linux machine, I don't need to distribute any additional OpenGL libraries with my program?

If so, which libraries are that - "opengl.dll", "libopengl.lib" or what?

Comment: OpenGL is usually exposed as part of the platform. For Windows, Microsoft has been shipping an OpenGL interface (opengl.lib) in its platform SDKs forever. I'm not sure exactly how you go about building .a for mingw linker out of those, but it is definitely different from using mesa.

Comment: Mesa itself is a software implementation. On GNU/Linux, beside the software implementation, it also includes DRI (direct rendering interface) which allows writing hardware accelerated drivers for GL.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no need to compile Mesa3D for MinGW. MinGW includes the GL library; it's just not called `libGL.a` nor `libGLU.a`; the libraries are instead called `libopengl32.a` and `libglu32.a`. Sadly, this is what Microsoft decided to call them under Windows on Visual Studio, so both Windows and GNU/Linux release of MinGW decided to include the libraries named as above.

So, when cross compiling for Windows, just change:

```
-lGL -lGLU
```

into

```
-lopengl32 -lglu32
```

---

Mesa3D on GNU/Linux is actually a name for a *libre* implementation of OpenGL. This is because OpenGL is a trademark, and SGI's policy did not allow for anyone to use the name without paying a hefty sum of money. Despite this, SGI provided the author, Brian Paul, a copy of the testing suite.

Mesa3D is on most platforms with native OpenGL implementation known as a software "sanity check" library with emulation of numerous high-end-hardware-only features. But on GNU/Linux, much more important is something called DRI or direct rendering interface. This is the real deal, the hardware acceleration and all. This library is also called Mesa3D; in fact, provisioning for DRI is a part of Mesa3D as well as of X11 and the kernel.

Mesa3D provides *libre* OpenGL-compatible headers on GNU/Linux and other free platforms.

**Summary:** Mesa3D is the name for the GNU/Linux implementation of OpenGL since that name is trademarked. This library includes an excellent, featureful, correct and relatively fast software implementation. It also includes direct rendering interface for hardware acceleration.

Comment: Thank you very much.
By the way, is there also precompiled libraries in my "native" gcc which I have on Linux or do I have to use mesa3d libraries when I am compiling for Linux?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "GNU/Linux release of MinGW". They are two seperate things. MinGW looks the same from all angles.

Comment: @rubenvb Why go nitpicking when you clearly understand what I meant?

Comment: Is this still the case in the current (sep'13) version of MINGW? I am browsing the installation manager for MINGW, but cannot find the OpenGL libraries in there.

Comment: @Bram I won't be checking the list of available packages as I am not running Windows on a day-to-day basis. But considering OpenGL has been a part of Windows since Windows 95, I would presume that in September 2013 OpenGL did not suddenly start coming as a separate library package. It should be  included in whatever Win32 API support package MinGW installer provides. Whenever I installed MinGW, or an IDE that includes MinGW, `opengl32` and `glu32` were always already there.