# When cross compiling an application for windows in linux, what libraries do I link?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, mingw, cross-compiling

If I'm compiling a Windows application on Linux using MinGW, do I link the Linux openal and opengl libraries or are there separate ones that come with MinGW? If so, where are they located?

Comment: The long and short of it is Yes. OpenAL and OpenGL are just standards, and there are many libraries/drivers out there that match that standard. So you have to choose one of those that matches your linux distribution/capabilities you are looking for.

Comment: So I can link the libGL.so, libGLEW.so, and libopenal.so that are in my /usr/lib64 and compile a PE using MinGW?

Comment: When I do that, everything compiles fine and then I get this: `Linking dynamic library: bin/Win64/Engine.dll` then the error `/usr/lib64/libGL.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized` pops up. So where's the libraries for MinGW at?

Comment: @Mike see here for OpenGL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989431/opengl-mesa-3d-mingw , mingw does not come with OpenAL afaik, so you will need to cross compile OpenAL for mingw first.